# why is the object instance context lost for public variables but not private variables?

Tags: javascript, oop

```
function myclass()
{
    var pri_var;
    this.pub_var;
    this.pub_func = function(which_object)
    {
        pri_var = which_object;
        this.pub_var = which_object + " pub";
    }
    this.pub_func1 = function()
    {
        console.log(this);
        alert(this.pub_var);
        alert(pri_var);
    }
}

instance1 = new myclass();
instance2 = new myclass();
instance1.pub_func("first");
instance2.pub_func("second");
//instance1.pub_func1();
//instance2.pub_func1();
function callCallback(callback1, callback2){
callback1("first");
callback2("second");
}
callCallback(instance1.pub_func1, instance2.pub_func1);
```

private varaibleis correctly noted, but public is undefined, as this points to window and not to myclass instance.

What is the solution for accessing public variable in callbacks defined inside class?

possible answer

```
function myclass()
{
    var pri_var;
    this.pub_var;
    var that = this;
    this.pub_func = function(which_object)
    {
        pri_var = which_object;
        that.pub_var = which_object + " pub";
    }
    this.pub_func1 = function()
    {
        console.log(this);
        alert(that.pub_var);
        alert(pri_var);
    }
}

instance1 = new myclass();
instance2 = new myclass();
instance1.pub_func("first");
instance2.pub_func("second");
//instance1.pub_func1();
//instance2.pub_func1();
function callCallback(callback1, callback2){
callback1("first");
callback2("second");
}
callCallback(instance1.pub_func1, instance2.pub_func1);
```

Comment: [Fiddled.](http://jsfiddle.net/MkYkz/)

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this to learn how `this` works.

Comment: You can use `instance1.pub_func1.call(instance1)` but honestly, whatever you're thinking on doing, it probably can be done a better way than this.

Comment: @FelixKling I used a "var that = this;" and then "that" to access public vars, is this the correct way to go?

Comment: That's the most common way. I use it in my library script. It's a good way to go.

Comment: You seem to have worked it out: keep a reference to the instance in a closure. I prefer to use the instance name instead of *that*, so in this case `var myclass = this`. I'll avoid the obvious "there are no classes in javascript, everything is an object". ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In ECMAScript, *this* is not "context", it is a property of an execution context that is usually set by **how the function is called**, or in ES5 by using *bind*. I'll ignore bind in this answer since you aren't using it.

When you do:

```
callCallback(instance1.pub_func1, ...);
```

what is passed to *callCallback* is a reference to the function, so when it's called its *this* is not set. In ES3 and ES5 non–strict mode, if *this* isn't set in the call, it is set to the global object (window in a browser).

So in `pub_func1` function:

```
console.log(this);
```

will return the global object and in strict mode it will return `undefined`. There are many articles on the web explaining how *this* works in ECMAScript, read a few as most aren't very good on their own, then ask further questions here if needed.

Comment: He already stated that he knows `this` is the global object. Your answer is useless, no offense.

Answer (score 0):

Your function

```
this.pub_func1 = function()
{
    console.log(this);
    alert(this.pub_var);
    alert(pri_var);
}
```

is being asked to accept a parameter on this call:

```
callCallback(instance1.pub_func1, instance2.pub_func1);

function callCallback(callback1, callback2){
   callback1("first");
   callback2("second");
}
```

Ensure that your functions are set up to accept variables passed to them, and RobG's comments regarding context are key as well. However, this issue is likely due to tangled syntax.

Answer (score 0):

*this* does not reference the same thing in different functions. Store a reference to myclass, then use it in the public functions.

```
function myclass()
{
    var pri_var;
    var that = this;
    this.pub_func = function(which_object)
    {
        pri_var = which_object;
        that.pub_var = which_object + " pub";
    }
    this.pub_func1 = function()
    {
        console.log(that);
        alert(that.pub_var);
        alert(pri_var);
    }
}

instance1 = new myclass();
instance2 = new myclass();
instance1.pub_func("first");
instance2.pub_func("second");
//instance1.pub_func1();
//instance2.pub_func1();
function callCallback(callback1, callback2){
callback1("first");
callback2("second");
}
callCallback(instance1.pub_func1, instance2.pub_func1);
```